# Is there any alternate command of ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am making project on Hospital Management Information System using c#, and want to insert data to SQL Server from c#, but ExecuteNonQuery Command is not working. Is there any alternate of this command?

```
connection.Open();
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: _Command is not working_ Please [edit] your question and explain how exactly it does not work. Some exceptions?

Comment: what does your `sql` look like in `command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);`

Comment: In addition to explaining what you mean by _not working_, it would be useful to show the SQL contained in the `sql` variable

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery returns a value indicating the number of rows changed.  If you are getting zero is usually means 1) You are doing an Insert and the Primary Key is already in the database.  Solution is to use Update 2) You are doing an update and the primary key is not in the database.  Solution is to use insert 3) The database you are changing is not the one you are checking and find is wasn't changing 4) The Command Text has Errors.  Solution is to run the query in SSMS which will give much better errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code, I hope it helps you.

```
try
{
    string connectionStringMS = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Your Connection String Name"].ConnectionString; // WebConfig
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringMS)) 
    using (SqlCommand nonqueryCommand = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.AppendLine(" INSERT INTO customer ");
        sqlBuilder.AppendLine(" (firstName, lastname) ");
        sqlBuilder.AppendLine(" VALUES ");
        sqlBuilder.AppendLine(" (@firstName, @lastname)");

        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = "Brad";
        nonqueryCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = "Test";

        nonqueryCommand.CommandText = sqlBuilder.ToString();

       nonqueryCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

Regards,

Comment: This is a good answer. If you added some explanation about what this code does and why it is better this would be a fantastic answer.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your feedback, I'll improve it